# Debugging Chrome -> Google Cast messaging

Tags: google-chrome, google-cast

Neither the "Sending" web page nor the background page for the Chrome extension display any network/web socket traffic when building a webapp around casting. For example, the discovery mechanism does not show any traffic, nor does the undocumented `api.sendMessage` method. For all I can tell, `api.sendMessage` does not do anything at all, since there is no error message  displayed and the debugger connected to the Google Cast does not show the message being received (even though it does show ping/pong and the initial launch message just fine).

Has anyone achieved sending/receiving a custom message from a Chrome webapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arg. I'm answering my own stupid questions as I go, and leaving them here in case others have problems.

Make sure you are passing the activityId properly. The current (1.0) version of the Cast API will not give any errors/warnings if you pass null.

Comment: i am trying to pass messages between the sender and receiver in a chrome app.  do you have an example on how do accomplish this?

Comment: @Fisch I've been playing around here: https://github.com/nickspacek/chromecast/tree/gh-pages